# clickable content on a transparent bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, transparency, navbar

right now i have a transparent bootstrap navbar with some content in it.

css

```
.navbar {
    /*background-color: #0B76BC;*/
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    color: #F5F5EF;
     border: 0;
     z-index: -100;
}
```

even though my navbar is transparent the content inside is not. but now the items are no clickable. So my question is it possible to have items still functioning on a transparent bootstrap navbar?

Comment: Why are you using `z-index: -100;` ?

Comment: ahhhhhhh im an idiot that was def, not helping! thank youuuuu

Comment: I am glad i could help :)

Comment: what does your HTML look like? But yeah, get rid of the z-index

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove `z-index: -100;`